# Questions regarding concept of Derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

There are 2 question I come across 
1)Assume f has finite derivative at each point of open interval (a,b).Assume that $\lim_{x\to c} f'(x)$ exists and is finite for some interior point c .Then prove that value of limit must be $f'(c)$
Difficulty regarding this question is that I think Derivative of function at point is limit .Here with statement state as f has finite derivative so derivative limit must exist at all interior point .So it is trivial that f'(c)=$\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)$ .
Or Is this question wanted to prove that at c derivative is continuous.I had difficulty regarding this concept .
2) Let f is continuous on (a,b)with a finite derivative f' everywhere in (a,b)except at c .If $\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)$ exist and has value A then show that f'(c) must also exist and value A.

 I had same problem in both of this question as what is difference between **f'(c)** and **$\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)$**
Any help will be appreciated .Please help me out I was not able to capture this basis notion I had read many book Still this problem Persist.
Thanks

Comment: You seem to think that if the derivative exists then it must be continuous, but that is the only way that you would be able to state that it is “trivial” that $f’(c) = \lim_{x\to c}f’(x)$. That assertion isn’t “the derivative exists”, it’s “the derivative is continuous at $c$”.

Comment: The derivative is just a function.  Do you understand the difference between $f(c)$ and $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)?$

Comment: But Sir many time in book Just I state example Rudin POMA page 105,In theorem 5.5 Assumption is that f'(x) is exist .That means what Sir. Is this meaning f' is exist at x or continous at x

Comment: Yes I understand Difference between function value and limit but problem is that Just above given comments I not able to interpret meaning in some sentence , In above comment reference In that proof ,due to that statement author had written f(t)-f(x)=(t-x)[f'(x)+u(t)]

Comment: where u(t)$\to 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d=\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)$; you want to prove that $d=f'(c)$, that is, that$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}h=d.$$Take $\varepsilon>0$. There is a $\delta>0$ such that $|h|<\delta\implies\bigl|f'(c+h)-d\bigr|<\varepsilon$. So, if $|h|<\delta$, then, by the mean value theorem, $\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}h=f'(c^\star)$ for some $c^\star$ between $c$ and $c+h$; in particular $c^\star=c+h^\star$ for some $h^\star$ such that $|h^\star|<|h|<\delta$ and so$$\left|\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}h-d\right|=\bigl|f'(c+h^\star)-d\bigr|<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: Sir Excellent Solution. But I had one doubt. How can We write |f'(c+h)-d|< $\epsilon$ .We only have info that f has finite derivative at each point .Is this due to Intermediate value property of Derivatives?

Comment: @SRJ There was a typo; I meant $\bigl|f'(c+h^\star)-d\bigr|<\varepsilon$. I hope that everyting is clear now.

Comment: Sir I mean on $3^{rd}$ line as you have written $|f'(c+h)-d|<epsilon $ .

Comment: @SRJ That's because $\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)=d$.

Comment: Thanks A lot Sir .....This thing Has been Cleared my all doubts regarding Derivatives....@José Carlos Santos